# include length text as covariate or offset in negative binomial regression model

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, offset

I have a dataset that contains the number of devices used to express casual relations in a text. I've constructed a Negative Binomial Regression to estimate the effect of Educational Level (3 levels) on the number of casual devices. However, I need to control for the fact that each text has different amount of words. If I am using a negative binomial model (glm.nb), should the total_words be included as offset in the model? I have included it as fixed effect, treated as a covariate.

Can anyone shed some light into how to choose between these two options? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a good solution to include (logarithm of) number of words as an offset in the model. There are similar questions here, have a look at

- [When are offsets useful in regressions involving literacy data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/634787/when-are-offsets-useful-in-regressions-involving-literacy-data/634928#634928)
- [Offset term in negative binomial regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395705/offset-term-in-negative-binomial-regression)